# Access IIS root directory from Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I have shared `appsettings` in `SharedSettings` folder.
I am deploying all the asp.net core application in sub directory.

For development, I have created as site with the following directory

```
c://Website
```

Here I am keeping my `sharedsettings`.

But I am developing application from another folder. Here I have configured my application to run as sub application in the web sites.
Folder could be
c://Applications/App1

I want to include the sharedsettings.json in my application. So I have tried the following approach.

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

    var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "..", "Shared");

    config
        .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: true) // When running using dotnet run
        .AddJsonFile("SharedSettings.json", optional: true) // When app is published
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
```

But whenever I have tried to get the hosted url path, It always current application hosted directory. (I understand the reason for the result).

**But I don't know how to get the root directory path where it is pointing to the different location.**

Reference:
https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/

[image: Deployed Website Structure]

Comment: any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Comment: @BrandoZhang, thank you for your concern. I haven't try yet. I will try and surely update to you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, the only way to achieve your requirement is using [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/11.1.0?_src=template) library to select the site root path according to the asp.net core application root path.

Notice: If you want to use Microsoft.Web.Administration, you should make sure your application pool contains enough permission to access the `applicationhost.config` file.

Normally, we will need localsystem permission. About how to modify application pool permission, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#configuring-iis-application-pool-identities).

Codes:

```
            string path = env.ContentRootPath;
            ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
            //the root path is the parent website's root path
            string rootpath = "";
            foreach (var site in mgr.Sites)
            {
                foreach (var application in site.Applications)
                {
                    foreach (var virtualDirectory in application.VirtualDirectories)
                    {
                        if (virtualDirectory.PhysicalPath == path)
                        {
                            rootpath = site.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories.Where(x=>x.Path=="/").Single().PhysicalPath;
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```